# How shall I understand this short text?

Tags: reading-comprehension

I have this little text here where I am not entirely sure how to understand the second sentence.

> ほかの会社から特許の使用料をもらう利益と技術がほかの会社に流れて結局は自分の会社の技術力が低くなる危険性とを比べ、会社が後者を選択するようになったのです。

Does it mean that the companies rather see their ideas used by other companies when it means to avoid patent battle in the court?

I am also unsure if the correct answer is one or two as they seem quite similar in meaning.

Can someone help me with this text?

> 「ブラックボックス」
>
> 最近、技術の「ブラックボックス」化と言って自分の会社が開発した技術を特許出願せず、秘密にする会社が出てきました。**ほかの会社から特許の使用料をもらう利益と技術がほかの会社に流れて結局は自分の会社の技術力が低くなる危険性とを比べ、会社が後者を選択するようになったのです。**
> 　２０００年ごろから日本の電子業界ではこうする会社がかなり増加してきました。会社は特許を出せば使用料でお金を得ることができますが、もし特許の裁判が起きた場合にはたくさんのお金と長い時間がかかります。それを嫌ったのです。
>
> 問題１　なぜ「ブラックボックス」化が広まりましたか。
> １　特許を受け取り使用料より裁判費用のほうが高いからです。
> ２　裁判をしなければならなくなるからです。
> ３　技術が漏{も}れたり裁判の煩{わずら}わしさの恐れが生まれるからです。
> ４　せっかく得た技術が全部盗まれてしまうからです。

Comment: BTW What does it mean: "the companies rather see their ideas used by other companies when it means to avoid patent battle in the court"?

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think that's what the sentence is saying.

> ほかの会社から特許の使用料をもらう利益

= (A) the profits received from other companies using the companies patents

**と** (AND)

> 「技術がほかの会社に流れて結局は自分の会社の技術力が低くなる危険性」

= (B) and because of the outcome of technical skills passing on to other companies, there is a risk that their own company's technological level are becoming lower.

> を比べ、

Comparing (A) and (B)

> 会社が後者を選択するようになったのです。

It is the case that companies are selecting the latter (B).

---

That's at least how I translate it.

I would have picked 4 myself but that's because I failed to read the first sentence at all. As naruto suggests 3 would be the correct answer since it lists both demerits.

(one of the most helpful hints for studying for the JLPT I learned was that for Japanese reading comprehensions you should never infer. [unlike the GRE which often asks the reader to infer])

Comment: 裁判については最後から2番目の文で言及しています。挙げられている2つのデメリットの両方をカバーしているので、3の選択肢が最も適切かなと思います。

Comment: @narutoさん教えてくれてありがとうございます。職場出る前読んでいて、左側のぼやけた字を読んでなかった。

Comment: 『「ほかの会社から特許の使用料をもらう利益」(=A)と、「技術がほかの会社に流れて結局は自分の会社の技術力が低くなる危険性」(=B)とを比べて、後者(=B)を選ぶ』ってことですよね・・・。「技術がほかの会社に流れて結局は自分の会社の技術力が低くなる危険性」とは、「risk of 自分の会社の技術力が低くなる as a result of 技術がほかの会社に流れる」

Comment: @Shokoさんいつもありがとうございます！勉強になっています。北海道に来られば、おごるよ！